# Android SQLite Disk IO Errors 3850/778/1034

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

Lately we are getting the following error  :

```
"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error - 
SQLITE_IOERR_WRITE (Sqlite code 778), (OS error - 9:Bad file descriptor)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)\n\t
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:576)\n\t
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:450)\n\t
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:414)\n\t
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:549)
```

or this :

```
"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I\\/O error (code 1034)
#################################################################\\n
Error Code : 1034 (SQLITE_IOERR_FSYNC)
Caused By : Disk I/O error occurred during 'fsync' operation.(disk I\\/O error 
(code 1034))
#################################################################
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)\n\t
at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:679)\n\t
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:437)\n\t
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)\n\t
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:527)\n\t
```

These traces are from crash reporting for the app and we cannot reproduce this issue.

SQLite error 778 was a reported issue on android OS version 4.1.x but it is said to be fixed but we are getting this errors for OS version ranging from 4.x.x to 7.x.x

We use the standard implementation for SQLite databases :

```
try {
  // Database access read/write
  // Transactions
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
}
finally {
   // End transactions and close cursors
}
```

The SqliteOpenHelper instance as well as the dao class that uses this helper are singleton .

It seems that this error is encountered randomly on a "write" operation on the database because several read operations go through successfully before this crash.

I am also getting various "Cannot open database" errors.
After quite some debugging, I finally got to know about leaking file descriptors via a HandlerThread or a incorrect Looper class usage. I am leaking one thread but that thread is rarely being called and the number of open file descriptors do not exceed 256 or the hard limit of 1024 in any case.
What can be the reason of such exception? Does file descriptor leak cause such issues in SQLite databases?

Any help is greatly appreciated, being stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: "Disk I/O error" is likely to be a hardware problem outside of your control.

Comment: But this error recently started to pop up. The only difference I find between my old and new code is leaking a rarely used Looper thread. I dont know if that could be the reason.

Comment: @SumeetDevidan did you find any solution for this?